# Python search list value using 'consist of'

Tags: python, list, search

I need your help with my code below:

I have a series list value and I wanted to search a word and it will return a number as shown below;

```
search_word = 'cp'

keyword_list = [[1, 'ap'],
                [2, 'cp'],
                [3, 'mc']]

for each_word in keyword_list:
    if search_word in each_word[1]:
        print(each_word[0])
```

The above code will print '2' which is fine but when I set **search_word = 'from cp'**, it doesn't match anything. Any help would be highly appreciated.

or any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the `in` (`__contains__`) test operands:

```
if each_word[1] in search_word:
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary would be one pythonic solution:

```
keyword_list = [[1, 'ap'],
                [2, 'cp'],
                [3, 'mc']]

d = {v: k for k, v in keyword_list}

d['cp']  # 2
```

If the substring condition "consists of" is important, you can subclass `dict`:

```
keyword_list = [[1, 'apab'],
                [2, 'cpcd'],
                [3, 'mcef']]

class dict_contains(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        keys = [k for k in self.keys() if k in value]
        key = keys[0] if keys else None
        return self.get(key)

d = dict_contains({v: k for k, v in keyword_list})

d['cpcde']  # 2
```